# How can I scale my bibliography section to a specific font size including the section name

Tags: bibliographies, fontsize

I would like to resize my bibliography section to a specific font size including the section name and so I'm wondering how can I do it maybe using `\scalebox{scale}{object}`.

Here is how I call my bibliography in the manuscript:

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrv} \bibliography{ref1}
```

Comment: Which document class are you using and how do you build your bibliography?

Comment: I'm using a poster class of Cambridge University `\documentclass[noback]{cuposter}`. But I don't think that it's gonna be a matter the use of any other class as long as it accepts the graphicx package.

Comment: And how do you build the bibliography? Could you please add to your question a simple mock-up complete document showing the relevant settings?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Actually I would like to know how to do it for any document class by adding the required package if needed.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `\fontsize{<nominal size>}{<baseline skip>}` command (followed by `\selectfont` to activate the selection)? For instance, if your main document has a fontsize of `{12}{14}` (12 pt font, 14pt distance between baselines), you could issue the command `\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont` to switch to a font that's 3pt smaller than the main text font. Do please tell us (a lot!) more about your TeX distribution, the fonts you have in mind, etc. Without such pieces of information, it's going to be rather difficult to provide specific advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cuposter` document class is based on `article`. To change the font inside the bibliography, one can use the [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package and `\AtBeginEnvironment` to use a different font (or simply a font size switch just before the `\bibliography` command); however, this won't affect the section title; to change this, one can use, for example, the [`sectsty`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) package and invoke `\sectionfont` with the desired modification just before the `\bibliography` command; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass[noback]{cuposter}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\tiny}{}{}

\begin{document}
\section{A regular Section}
...

\sectionfont{\tiny}%just before the \bibliographystyle command
\bibliographystyle{abbrv} 
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

Of course, instead of `\tiny` you can use any other of the font size switches or even `\fontsize{...}{...}\selectfont` for finer control.

Comment: Don't you also need to issue the command such as `\tiny` to influence the font size used in the bibliography itself (as you observe in the explanation before the MWE)?

Comment: @Mico this is done with the `\AtBeginEnvironment` line in my example (I know it might sound an overkill, but using this, there's no need to worry for explicitly grouping).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: The cuposter document class generates 3 columns. So I'm wondering can I put the acknowledgment as footnote along the whole width of the paper and not only at the third column.

Comment: @Bel since this is a completely new issue, feel free to open a new fresh question.